# Move "ImageView" instantly to another position (Without Animation) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-view

I've been googling for hours to do this the most efficient way possible (To be supported on all devices) but with no use:

I have an ImageView contained within a ConstraintLayout, so it has no absolute coordinates, it moves depending on the width of the device's screen.

What I wanna do is MOVE it to a new position with dp units not pixels. (So I make sure it's visually compatible across all devices)

For example, moving ImageView 10 dp to the left INSTANTLY.

I don't need animation, I just need instant translation. All the answers I've found include animation but I just want it to be as fast as instantaneous can be, other answers give the solution in terms of pixels.

I am using Kotlin. And I have no code for the moment that does anything properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to manually update the `ConstraintLayout`.
I don't know exactly how you have your views, so i'll just create an example.

In the XML, we have the initial position of the image view (imagine it's parent is a constraint layout):

```
 android:id="@+id/image_view"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 app:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

When then it comes to moving the image view, you would manually update the constraints, in this case, the right margin (to move it left):

```
val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout)
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
constraintSet.clear(R.id.image_view, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.image_view, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 40)
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

Updating the constraints seems a bit long winded but unfortunately that's just how they work (you make a copy or create a whole new set of constraints and apply it to the view).

In this example, you'd changing the right margin from 20dp to 40dp, shifting the image view right by 20dp instantly with no animation.

Comment: No problem! I was a bit unsure of whether it was pixels or dp (they've omitted the documentation here, so i'm assuming it's dp since that's what's used everywhere else). If not, it's a bit of a pain but you can manually convert pixels to DP by looking at the device density in the resources.

Yeah the ConstraintSet.END and START is a bit weird, it's so if the device is in Right-to-Left mode (e.g for displaying arabic text)... START gets flipped to right and END is now the left.

Comment: Thanks for setting that into light. I ended up tracing back the source code and it seems the mother class takes LayoutParams (which works in pixels) as one of the values. So in short, it does deal with pixels not dp which means extra work of converting dp to pixel (which I have never done). Thanks mate you have been a huge help !